# Pandas new column based on condition on two other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`df1` and `df2` are of different sizes. Set the `df1(row1, 'Z')` value to `df2(row2, 'C')` value when `df1(row1, 'A')` is equal to `df2(row2, 'B')`.

What is the recommended way to implement `df1['Z'] = df2['C'] if df1['A']==df2['B']`?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'test'], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['foo', 'baz'], 'C': [3, 1]})

df1
      A  b  c
0   foo  1  3
1   bar  2  4
2  test  3  5

df2
     B  C
0  foo  3
1  baz  1
```

After change

```
df1
      A  b  c  Z
0   foo  1  3  3
1   bar  2  4  NaN
2  test  3  5  NaN
```

What if there require multiple assignments following multiple conditions. Is iterating over rows recommended as shown below?

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if <condition(s)>:
        do assignment(s): df.at[i, 'hjk']=something
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data and the expected output for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.where`, passing the condition as `df1.A` equals `df2.B`, and for true boolean, take `df2.C` else take `df1.Z`:

```py
np.where(df1.A.eq(df2.B), df2.C, df1.Z)
```

Assign above result to `df1.Z`

**SAMPLE:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(5,10,20), 'Z': np.random.randint(5,10,20)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': np.random.randint(5,10,20), 'B': np.random.randint(5,10,20)})
```

```py
>>>df1.Z.values
Out[41]: array([7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 8, 9, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 8, 8, 9, 6, 7, 7])
>>> np.where(df1.A.eq(df2.B), df2.C, df1.Z)
Out[42]: array([7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 9, 7, 6, 9, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 9, 6, 7, 7])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to try `map`

```
df1['Z'] = df1['A'].map(dict(zip(df2['B'],df2['C'])))
```